# Cannot copy assembly.Unable to add the dll to website

Tags: c#

Iam getting the error "Cannot copy assembly.Unable to add the dll to website. The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" while building the .net application.

Comment: Can you ascertain whether it is locked for read (in the build folder) or for write (in the web-site folder)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to pick-up an assembly from the \bin directory of an already running web-application. If so is the case then you need to stop both the website and IIS application pool of the already running website. You will be able copy the assembly after this. After you complete your task, you can restart the IIS website and application pool.

You can also do this by stopping the IIS website only.